# Join result of set-returning function (json_array_elements) with table column

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, set-returning-functions

Let's say I have two tables:

User_Combination

```
+--------+----------------+
|   id   |   combination  |
+--------+----------------+
|    6   |     [1, 2]     |
|    9   |     [2, 3]     |
+--------+----------------+
```

Colors

```
+--------+----------------+
|   id   |   color        |
+--------+----------------+
|    1   |       Blue     |
|    2   |       Yellow   |
|    3   |       Green    |
+--------+----------------+
```

I'm trying to join the result of `json_array_elements(color)` with the `id` of Elements. For example, the result of

```
select json_array_elements(color) as CombinationID
from User_Combination where id = 6;
```

is

```
+-------------------+
|   CombinationID   |
+-------------------+
|    1              |
|    2              |
+-------------------+
```

I'm unable to join `CombinationID` with `Colors.id`. When I try an SQL command such as:

```
select json_array_elements(article_data) AS articlesInOutfits (color) as CombinationID
from User_Combination uc JOIN Colors co ON co.id = articlesInOutfits;
```

or

```
select json_array_elements(article_data) AS articlesInOutfits (color) as CombinationID
from User_Combination uc JOIN Colors co ON co.id = uc.articlesInOutfits;
```

It says `articlesInOutfits` does not exist.
Any advice?

Comment: Your version of Postgres?

Comment: Using 9.3.3. 
Surprisingly unnest isn't working.

Comment: Can you fix some confusing errors in your question? `json_array_elements(color) `? And what is `Elements` referring to? Actual table definitions showing data types and constraints would be much more useful.

Comment: It's a pity you don't have Postgres 9.4, which introduced `json_array_elements_text()`: http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54289/3684 Would be more convenient for this. But while you are stuck with Postgres 9.3, [at least uprgrade to the latest point release](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/). Yours is rather outdated.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, Erwin!  Will do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `unnest()` to get *unpacked* combinations:

```
select id, unnest(combination) cid
from user_combination;

 id | cid 
----+-----
  6 |   1
  6 |   2
  9 |   2
  9 |   3
(4 rows)
```

Use *unpacked* `cids` to join with `colors`:

```
select u.id, color
from (
    select id, unnest(combination) cid
    from user_combination
    ) u
join colors c
on cid = c.id;

 id | color  
----+--------
  6 | Blue
  6 | Yellow
  9 | Yellow
  9 | Green
(4 rows)
```

Use an aggregate function (e.g. `json_agg()`) to get joined colors aggregated for a user:

```
select u.id, json_agg(color)
from (
    select id, unnest(combination) cid
    from user_combination
    ) u
join colors c
on cid = c.id
group by 1;

 id |      json_agg       
----+---------------------
  9 | ["Yellow", "Green"]
  6 | ["Blue", "Yellow"]
(2 rows)
```

---

If `combination` is of type **`json`** you should use `json_array_elements()` in a lateral join:

```
select u.id, json_agg(color)
from (
    select id, cid
    from user_combination,
    lateral json_array_elements(combination) cid
    ) u 
join colors c
on cid::text::int = c.id
group by 1;
```

Comment: awesome, one sec and I'll try that out

Comment: I'm using Postgres version 9.3.3 and it says:  ERROR:  function unnest(json) does not exist

Comment: Ahh I see, I'm storing an array as the type json.  I'll fix that and then try unnest

Comment: I assumed `combination` is of type `int[]`. For `json` you should use `json_array_elements` as in the edited answer.

Comment: You're a beast.  Thanks so much for the help!!